# Hibernate: MySql vs ' ' user

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've started learning hibernate. Here is my hibernate-configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatelearning</property>
    <property name="connection.name">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>


    <!-- JDBC connection pool -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    <mapping resource="./Event.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The exception is:

```
INFO: connection properties: {name=root, password=****}
22.03.2011 15:45:14 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
WARNING: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'hibernatelearning'
```

Does anybody know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in hibernate.cfg.xml. The right one:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatelearning</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>


    <!-- JDBC connection pool -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    <mapping resource="./Event.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```